# Baixar PDF Node.js

Tags: node.js, pdf

Estou usando o Request para baixar um boleto da https://www.boletocloud.com/ que está em pdf.
Acontece que não consigo visualizar o pdf que baixei, os desenvolvedores da API falam que ele está em UTF-8, eu setei tudo mas mesmo assim não dá certo.

## request

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var options = { method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://sandbox.boletocloud.com/api/v1/boletos',
      headers:
       { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;',
         'postman-token': '058e9f74-644b-a03c-fc53-fbc46f3fe8b3',
         'cache-control': 'no-cache',
         'accept-charset': 'UTF-8',
         encoding: 'utf-8',
         authorization: 'Basic YXBpLWtleV9yODBfLVUyWHlWcjlsbFIwSXhMOUFGUkFRTnloUU11UF9SUnRZTmU1WnNjPTp0b2tlbg==' },
      form:
       { 'boleto.conta.banco': /* Outros campos... */ } };

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
      if (error) throw new Error(error);
      res.contentType("application/pdf; charset=utf-8");
      var utf8 = body.toString('utf8');
      res.send(utf8);
  });
```

Comment: Coloque a solução em uma resposta por favor, não somos um fórum, entenda o funcionamento do site: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Eu iria colocar como resposta, porém eu entendi que as recomendações era para responder. De qualquer forma vou alterar aqui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resovido usando a função pipe.**

```
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  /* CODIGO */ 
}).pipe(res);
```